# Why does Vim say "Already at newest change" despite a full "changes" history list?

Tags: undo-redo

I seem to be unable to undo something in a file I saved, despite that the history of changes shows up with I press `:changes`. So the change history is known to vim but I cannot access it?

I thought it was possible to go back to previous changes even after you save the file, but perhaps I am wrong. I also the get the "Already at" message with `g-` and `g+`.

Comment: You should be able to navigate the undo history independently from saving or not. You could have a look at [`:h :undolist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#%3Aundolist) to make sure you have things to undo. You should also have a look at [how to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) in case the issue comes from your configuration. Finally you should give us a detailed list of the actions you are doing (e.g. open a new buffer, append text, save with `:w`, press `u`), the results you got and the results you expected. This would be easier to help you debug this.

Answer (score 11):

The **change list** is a different thing from the **undo list**.

The [change list](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#changelist) is a list of *locations* of changes, and it can be viewed with `:changes` and navigated with e.g. `g;` and `g,`.

The `g+` and `g-` commands that you’re using move instead through the **undo list**. This is a [tree of different file states](https://vimhelp.org/usr_32.txt.html#32.2): it’s what you are navigating when you undo and redo changes. The undo list can be viewed with [`:undolist`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#%3Aundolist).

Vim only persists the undo list between sessions when you have **undo persistance** switched on: it is switched *off* by default.

Try adding [`set undofile`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undofile%27) to your `.vimrc` or read the documentation at [`:help undo-persistence`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#undo-persistence) for full details.

Comment: wow, that really clears things up. I didn't realize they were distinct lists!