# Why is my changelist not working?

Tags: vimrc, undo-redo

I'm using homebrew-installed vim

My changelist looks something like this:

```
   10   250    0 nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)
    9   266   11 set report=0
    8   267   20 set display+=lastline
    7   268    8 set title
    6   271    0 -invalid-
    5    75   23 set backspace=indent,eol
    4    76    6
    3    76    0
    2   271    0 -invalid-
    1   270    0 "this will be deleted
>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But when I type `g-`, I see the following message:

```
0 changes; before #1
```

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927016/vim-change-list-behaviour) indicates that the `-invalid-`'s are a bug.

Thoughts?  I'm not sure how else to use the changelist.

Comment: The cursor `>` is already at changes `0`. You cannot step back to change `-1`. `g+` will bring you to change `1`|.

Comment: `g+` results in `Already at newest change`

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing changelist and undolist

Seems `g-` and `g+` are for the undolist, not the changelist

[Why does Vim say "Already at newest change" despite a full "changes" history list?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26308/why-does-vim-say-already-at-newest-change-despite-a-full-changes-history-lis)